# Different write behavior for owner and member of group despite 775 permissions

Tags: permissions, samba, group

I have mounted a remote share via my fstab using the line:

```
//path/to/target /media/f cifs gid=<mygroup's id>,dir_mode=0775,file_mode=0775 0 0
```

As a result, everything under `/media/f` winds up with permissions that look like this:

```
$ ls -al
drwxrwxr-x 0 root mygroup ...
```

I have made the user `www-data` a member of `mygroup`, with the goal of allowing a Django webapp to write files within `/media/f`.  However, it doesn't work.  I get permission errors.

In an effort to fix the problem, I changed the mount line to set *both* the `gid` and `uid` so that the mount point has user `www-data` and group `mygroup`.  So now my mount point looks like this:

```
$ ls -al
drwxrwxr-x 0 www-data mygroup ...
```

And everything works fine.

The question: why is it that my webapp is able to write to `/media/f` when the that folder is owned by `www-data:mygroup` but not when it is owned by `root:mygroup` (knowing that `www-data` is a member of `mygroup`?

I have tried remounting as well as restarting in the hopes of getting the membership of `www-data` (the user) to the group `mygroup` to "stick" but it just doesn't work.

Oddly, when set up with the `root:mygroup` ownership, if I `sudo su www-data` and then try to write to `/media/f` from the terminal, everything works fine.  Any idea what's going on there?  It's as if the `uwsgi` process that's running django isn't really running with the full permissions I've tried to grant to `www-data`.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this was quite specific to the context described above.  I was using uWSGI to serve my site using emperor mode.  I set the parameters `uid=www-data` and `gid=www-data`.  I expected this to cause my vassal processes to have the permissions associated with the user and the group `www-data` *as well as* the permissions associated with any group to which `www-data` (the user) belongs.  This assumption is *incorrect*.  Vassals do not run (by default) with *any* supplementary group ids.

It turns out uWSGI (in recent versions) has a fix for this.  You can manually specify `add-gid=mygroup` in the uWSGI configuration.  You can specify this parameter many times to add as many gid's to a vassal process as your heart desires.  This feature is only available as of uWSGI 1.9.15 so you might need to upgrade to use this approach.

Full writeup [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27300540/uwsgi-process-doesnt-inherit-permissions-associated-with-group-its-uid-belongs/27360613#27360613).