# How to get the supplementary groups IDs of a process?

Tags: linux, process, group

I can use the following command to get the effective group ID of a process:

```
ps -o pid,egid
```

But how can I get the supplementary groups IDs of a process?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GID, current, primary, supplementary, effective and real group IDs?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18198/gid-current-primary-supplementary-effective-and-real-group-ids)

Comment: Ipor, that’s an informative link, but I don’t think it answers the question posed here: how to *get* those group ids.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) has these format specifiers:

```
supgid      SUPGID    group ids of supplementary groups, if any.  See getgroups(2).     
supgrp      SUPGRP    group names of supplementary groups, if any.  See getgroups(2).
```

So, `ps -o supgid` etc. Though if you use `supgrp` with some other columns, the default width might not fit all groups if there are many, so you may want to widen it, e.g.
 `ps -o pid,supgrp:100,args`

Answer (score 6):

On linux these are available for a process in `/proc/pid/status`:

```
-bash-4.2$ grep \^Groups /proc/$$/status
Groups: 6 9 11 18 100 1000
-bash-4.2$
```

it may be useful to read through the `proc(5)` manual for what is stored in the various `/proc` files.